# How do other PCs in the domain resolve the servername to an IP address?

Tags: networking, dns

My PC is in the Windows domain.
There's also an Ubuntu Server that sits on Hyper-V and hosts a local web server.
Let's say the Ubuntu Server's name is **userver**. In order to go to my web site I type **userver** in my browser. If I do the same on any other machine in the network I can still go to my website.
My question is: why? I haven't added any records to those PCs hosts files.
Does the Windows DNS server automatically create records for all the machines in the network?

Comment: Is the Ubuntu server AD-joined? Can you also access the server by its full domain name (userver.ad.example.com)?

Comment: No. I use apache2 to host my web site. In the virtualhost file the ServerName is userver. When I type systemd-resolve --status I get the Windows DNS domain name and the DNS server's IP address is the gateway.

Comment: you can confirm that a dns record exists with `nslookup userver <domain DNS server IP>`.  nslookup will query the dns server on your domain, without considering other sources.

Comment: @FrankThomas I did as you said. The result is:
`Server:  <Windows domain name>`
`Address: 192.168.1.1#53`
`Name: userver.<Windows domain name>`
`Address: <My Ubuntu server(userver)'s IP address>`
So, does this mean that the Windows DNS server is configured to add records for every machine in the network? Also, does this mean that if the machine where Hyper-V is used to host my Ubuntu Server is in he domain than the guest OS will automatically be in the domain as well?

Comment: Domain member systems are usually set up to perform DDNS registration, so they pull a DHCP IP, and register it with the AD domains DNS servers. it looks like your server has been joined to the domain, or at least configured for DDNS registration, or someone manually added a name for it. it doesn't seem like you can answer the questions about the network configuration that would be necessary for us to tell more. either way, the configuration you describe is common, and non-surprising.